# After installing Delphi 7 on new Windows 7 pc, I always get ' Source has been modified. Rebuild ? ' when debugging. Why?

Tags: delphi, debugging, ide, delphi-7

I just installed **Delphi 7** on a new **Windows 7 pc**.

Everything finally works, but every time I now encounter a breakpoint and press F7 or F8 to step further I get the `' Source has been modified. Rebuild ? '`  question.

I never had that on other pc's.

Anyone know what is causing this prompt ?

I have 'Autosave : Editor files' and 'Project desktop' checked in the environment options, and I have CnPack installed.

**UPDATE**

When I **prevent CnPack from loading** ( *when holding the shift key when starting Delphi 7, you get a form where you can disable all of the CnPack extensions* ), **the problems disappears**.

So it's certainly one of their wizards.

Since there are a lot of them , I may not find which one immediatly.

But when I do, I will edit my question once more ...

Or if someone else finds it , please add you answer here.

Comment: Maybe you can monitor what happens with SysInternals [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). If you own a Win7 Pro license, I would recommend that you convert the XP Mode VM with VMware Player and set up a development VM.

Comment: Did you install Delphi 7 in C:\Program Files? It could be the cause of such file writing issue (UAC virtual directories).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit.

When CnPack installed : choose '**CnPack - IDE Enhancements settings - Version enhancements**'.

When one of both of the check boxes in the form are checked ('*Insert compile time into version info*' and/or '*Auto-increment build number*', the question of the modified source is asked **every time** you want to step through your source.

When the check boxes are cleared, no such question is asked.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is like closing the barn door after the horse has escaped, I suggest you install both DDevExtensions and DelphiSpeedup.  One or the other of these will suppress the prompt you're getting.

http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/

These are good tools for many other reasons too!

Comment: DDevExtensions will disable the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** To investigate if UAC/Administrator issues influence this:

> <strike>Install Delphi 7 in the XP-Mode of
>   Windows 7 should solve this problem.</strike>
>
> If not, be sure to run it as
>   Administrator, and disable UAC as the
>   [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107123/how-to-install-delphi-7-on-vista) suggest.

The reason for this investigation is that UAC introduced two security tokens for an administrator: the first token has the 'normal user' role, the second the 'elevated user role'. Under some circumstances, the elevated role can influence the normal role, but not otherwise.

That didn't solve it, so something else must be changing your files.

Where are your files stored? Remote? Local? Which directory?

Download and install [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), then watch the files that Delphi thinks are modified.
Then look what other process tries to touch those files.

If the 'other processs' that changes the timestamp on the files is Delphi itself then:

Do you have 3rd party components and experts installed in Delphi?
If so, try to disable them one by one and see if the problem persists.

--jeroen

Comment: Disabling UAC is a terrible idea, and so is running the IDE as Admin. Both of those mean that you can't test for usability on your end users machines that are not running as Admin or with UAC off. You should learn to work with UAC and not fight against it.

Comment: nope - tried both settings. Both produce the same question every time I compile/run a project ( even without changing one character in an open editor ). Must be some other setting.

Comment: This is a very poor solution. Delphi 7 runs fine on Windows 7 and XP mode is horrid.

Comment: @Ken, @David: I was not so much against Delphi 7 on Windows 7 (it can run fine without UAC), but wanting to know if that solved the `Source has been modified.` issue. Apparantly, it does not. See my edit for a new suggestion.